# Gitlab CI. mvn verify. Failed to execute goal

Tags: maven, kotlin, continuous-integration, gitlab

I tried build locally:

```
mvn -B verify
```

All works fine.

.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: maven:latest

verify-job:
  script:
    - mvn -B verify
```

After checked several modules maven. I get error:

```
[INFO] Tree 1.0-0 ......................................... FAILURE [  7.587 s]
```

... SKIPPED

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:35 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-25T13:51:57Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project Tree: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :Tree
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

no module uses dependency org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin
I checked another answers on SO with the same error, no one is related with CI GitLab integration.
I can guess it's related to ktlint, but why local builds are successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution:
just add to pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can go for the solution, your pipeline need to be define jdk package add:

Just make sure about the java version as per your project needs:

```
Java_Build:
  stage: build
  image: 
    name: docker:20.10
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add openjdk8
    - apk add maven
  script:
    - mvn -B verify
```